Windows 10 - Third monitor not activated
I am facing a problem with detection and activation of the third monitor connected to my computer. The setting is the following:

Graphics card is a Strix RX580.
2 monitors connected via display port
1 monitor connected via hdmi.

At first, the computer would boot with only one of the DP connected monitor on. In Windows settings, I could see all three monitors being detected. Only the following precise sequence would allow to use all monitors:

Extend desk to monitors 1 and 2.
Duplicate monitor 2 to monitor 3.
Extend desk to all monitors.

At the last step, the monitors would flicker two to three times and would finally come on and be usable. If I tried to activate monitor 3 before 2, or extend the desk to monitor 3 directly (instead of step 2), or pretty much any other variation, it would lead to either of the following:

Windows would offer to save the changes while no change has been applied and the third monitor is still deactivated.
All already activated monitors would flicker every second or so, until the timer to save the changes would expire.

While it was annoying to reconfigure the display settings at each boot using the described protocol, it was working. Recently, this stopped. Windows boots with the 2 DP connected monitors on and the third (hdmi) monitor detected, however, it is impossible to activate it.
Additional details:

AMD drivers are the latest.
Booting the computer with uBuntu activates all three monitors flawlessly.
2 graphics cards have been tested with the same results.
Can't upgrade to Windows 11 due to the motherboard not handling TPM 2.0

Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Sounds like a windows driver issue. Have you tried reverting back to an older driver ?
